# What does "preparing for copy/move" do in Finder?

Tags: finder, filesystem

This question has been around for a dozen of years, but all answers concentrate on how to speed up and usually date back quite a while. Contratry to that, I'd like to understand what phases Macos goes through when copying/moving a file. I've recently encountered that an interrupted move operation on hundreds of files (in Finder) left a lot of zero-sized files in the target location (on a NAS). All those files were shown greyed-out, and copying over them resulted in error. I could however delete them (very slowly in Finder, very quickly, but still not instantaneously in with `rm *.jpg` in Terminal) and restart moving the originals again.

So I wonder:

- What does this preparation actually do (why not copy-move straight away)
- What are those ghost files?
- What makes Finder show them greyed-out?

Comment: Preparing is creating the list of file to be copied. Moving from one disk to another is copy : first copy all files to destination, then delete from source. Grey files are entries created before all files have been copied so cancelling move will go faster. These may not be  complete and usable files and potentially deleted if action is cancelled so finder tells you « don’t use these files »

Comment: @PtitXav Thanks for the comment. I still wonder why not just copy files one by one, like Windows does. Also, it seems that copying/moving many files takes more time (due to this long preparation process) than if I ask Finder to move the files in small chunks. So I still wonder what it actually is doing. It doesn't sound plausible that preparation takes more time than the actual move. Unless, of course, this preparation is in fact doing something useful. But what?!

Comment: creating a file is different process between Windows and Unix (like MacOS). On Unix you get a new entry number ( file id) in the table of id, then you copy the file bloc by bloc setting each bloc as used in the table if blocs. Then you add the file name with its id in the directory file. On wUnix a directory is just a file with correspondance between a file name and a file id. Preparing copy need to analyse the full directory structure, the files sizes to compute the destination structure and bloc allocation. Windows has a different approach (I do not know exactly)

Comment: @PtitXav thanks for the elaboration, however I still cannot make sense of it. It seems, at least, that copying/moving the same amount of files and MB's in Terminal takes much less time (starts immediately). Also, alternative file managers, also start copying right away. It really seems to be a Finder issue. So I don't think it's OS-related, even if files are managed differently in Windows and MacOS.

Comment: There may also be a part where Finder does not start copy/move before it is sure there is enough space in destination and preparing for the case of destination files with ssme name already existing. Somme app start copying without taking this into account and may seems to start the copy faster. (Just guessing)